# cronjob says "/bin/sh: 1: root: not found"

Tags: 18.04, cron

My cronjob command are below and I get this email daily. I'm trying to reboot server (ubuntu 18.04) every night. What is the issue here?

```
MAILTO="ggeeeryit@gmail.com"
30 2 * * 1 /usr/bin/letsencrypt renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
0 4 * * * root /sbin/reboot
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cronjobs created via `crontab -e` are run as the user who
issues that command and thus owns that cronjob. You cannot
supply a user in the line

```
0 4 * * * root /sbin/reboot
```

to have that job run as `root`. If that was the case, one
could run arbitrary commands as another user. Nobody would
want that.

When you want to run a cronjob as user `root` you must issue

```
sudo crontab -e
```

to edit `root`'s crontab – not yours. Drop the user specification,
i.e. add the following line:

```
0 4 * * * /sbin/reboot
```

**But** there is also the possibility to define cronjobs in
files below `/etc/cron.d`. In that case the syntax is a bit different
and the first column after the time specification must contain the
user as whom the job is to be run. But that syntax is only applicable
to files below `/etc/cron.d`.